Controlling VOUT with ESP32 DAC on PL5501
I'm doing a Buck/Boost controller with a PL5501 The input voltage will be between 3.6-4.2 V and output voltage will be between 1-8 V.
According with datasheet, this s the typical application

The idea is that I can control VOUT with the DAC of a ESP32 and for that I'm thinking in the next solution:



As you can see, VADJ pin is the reference for control VOUT level. If I apply a voltage directly to this pin, I can control the reference of the VOUT equation

I think if I use R1=130 kΩ and R2=100 kΩ and apply 0.5 V from the DAC, VOUT will be 1.15 V, and if apply 3.3 V VOUT will be 7.59 V. Close enough for me.
What do you think? Can this work?
